# How to clone a document in MongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using MongoDB and am trying to clone a document and cannot for the life of me figure this out - what's frustrating me is that I know this is probably very simple indeed but it seems my brain has blocked, so here it is:

I am trying to automate a process which involves cloning a document in the `users` collection of my Mongo database. The process goes like this:

1. Clone user with email `testing@company.com`
2. Modify some attributes (email, name, etc.) and save the new document

Basically, I am just trying to do what the "clone document" button does in MongoDB Compass but can't figure it out.

My problem is that when I try to do this in python my `testing_user` keeps being overwritten when I call `await db().save(user)`. I thought about creating a blank new `user` and adding the attributes manually but I'm sure there must be a better way to do this. All of my google searches have returned hits about cloning entire databases or collections, does someone know of a better way to do this?

---

Relevant lines from my (not functioning) script:

```
testing_user = await db().find_one(User, User.email == "testing@company.com")
new_user = testing_user
new_user.attr1 = "foo"
new_user.attr2 = "bar"
await db().save(new_user)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `find_one()` without getting the `_id` field, you can then manipulate the object and then insert it back to the same (or any other) collection using `insert_one()`. Try this:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}) # Test data - 1 record
record = db.mycollection.find_one({}, {'_id': 0})
#
# make changes to the record here if needed
#
db.mycollection.insert_one(record)

for item in db.mycollection.find():
    print(item)
```

prints 2 items:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6176f2dbe4a52fa03307796e'), 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
{'_id': ObjectId('6176f2dbe4a52fa03307796f'), 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```